# fontforge building in brew, terminal cant find gcc error

Tags: gcc, terminal, homebrew, fontforge

This is my first time trying to compile source code in terminal (I installed gimp using macPorts but this could be part of the problem...?)

I want to install fontforge and I was following these instructions [how to install fontforge](http://joewong.blogspot.com.au/2011/11/how-to-install-fontforge-on-mac-os-x.html).

I got this warning while installing brew:

```
Warning: The following *evil* dylibs exist in /usr/local/lib
They may break builds or worse. You should consider deleting them:
/usr/local/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib
```

I could not find usr/local/lib and the only libssl file was in opt/local/lib called libssl.1.0.0.dylib which is supposed to be hidden apparently...

I made it to the "brew install cairo --use-clang" step, then when I try the "brew install fontforge --use-gcc" step I get the following warning:

```
Warning: It appears you have MacPorts or Fink installed.
Software installed with other package managers causes known problems for
Homebrew. If a formula fails to build, uninstall MacPorts/Fink and try again.
==> Installing fontforge dependency: gettext
Error: GCC could not be found
```

when I check gcc version I get:

```
:~ me$ gcc --V
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: no input files
```

Do I need to uninstall macports (then re-install gimp?)
I read gcc comes with xcode, I have xcode 4.3 (upgraded after this issue but didn't fix it) so do I have gcc or not? is there another way to check etc.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong (what I broke etc)?

NOTE I also have flashbuilder which has a program called gcc as well (I dont know if this broke the other gcc...)